# Delete header 'content-type' from request headers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to remove content-type header from the post request

```
const config = {
  transformRequest: [
    function(data, headers) {
      // Do whatever you want to transform the data
      console.log(headers);
      delete headers.post["content-Type"];
      delete headers.get["content-Type"];
      delete headers.common["content-Type"];
      console.log(headers);
      return data;
    }
  ]
};
const request1 = axiosObject.post(urlAPI + "delete/post", post, config);

request1.then(res => {
  console.log(res);
});
```

But this is not working.
When i console log headers, there is no content-type in it,
but when i see request headers, **Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8** is present

Comment: Why do you want to remove the `Content-Type` header?

Comment: This sounds like you're asking about your attempted solution, not the actual problem. What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: It's `Content-Type`, not `content-Type`. Case is significant.

Comment: I have tried both Content-type and content-type.

Comment: @ChrisG what i need to do is to send post request without any content-type.

Comment: @Sandhu Yes, I get that. But *why*? (read: [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/))

Comment: @ChrisG i am kind of lost. In backend, spring i am getting error "The current request is not a multipart request", backend team has setup it to not accept "Content-Type" and they take form data only to upload a file and other vairables

Comment: @ChrisG they are not even accepting multipart form data content type

Comment: @Sandhu Why would the backend team set up the server to reject requests that have a `Content-Type` header? That's total nonsense.

Comment: Trying them to do it.